# Linked list implementation in C?

Tags: c, list

The following code is a single linked list implementation in c. every time the function `addtoqueue` is being called, it creates a node and appends the node to the end of the list. The pointer list points to the first node of the linked list, but every time I update the value of node using input (the values are read from client connection), all the previous nodes in the linked list gets the last filename that has been inputed. i.e:

**after 1st node creation (abc.txt as input):** linked list has one node with value abc.txt;

**after 2nd node (xyz.txt as input):** linked list has two nodes with same filename xyz.txt.(instead of one node with abc and one node with xyz)

There's my implementation below, what end where is the logical failure?

```
struct listdata
{
   char *filename;
   struct listdata *next;
}*list;                         

void addtoqueue(int client,char *value) 
{   
   char buffer[512];
   char filepath[100];
   struct listdata *temp,*input;

   input=(struct listdata *)malloc(sizeof(struct listdata));

   read(client,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
   d = sscanf(buffer,"%s",filepath);

   input->filename=&filepath;   

   if(list == NULL)
   {
       list=input;   
       list->next=NULL;
   }
   else if((list->next)==NULL)  
   {
      list->next=input;
      input->next=NULL;
   }
   else 
   {
      temp=list->next;
      while((temp->next)!=NULL)
      {
         temp=temp->next;
      }
      temp->next=input;
      input->next=NULL;
   }
   //list points to the first node
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simpler

```
void addtoqueue(int client,char *value)
{
  char buffer[512];

  char filepath[100];

  struct listdata *temp=NULL,*input=NULL;

  input=(struct listdata *)malloc(sizeof(struct listdata));

  read(client,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
  d=sscanf(buffer,"%s",filepath);

  input->filename=&filepath;   
  input->next = NULL;

  if(list == NULL)
  {
    list=input;   
  }
  else
  {
    temp=list;

    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {
      temp=temp->next;
    }
    temp->next=input;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the full code for linked list..
this will definately help you
visit http://codingloverlavi.blogspot.in/2013/12/singly-linked-list.html for more details

```
//Single LinkList
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node*next;
};

typedef struct Node Node;
Node*sort2(Node*,Node**);
Node*sort(Node*start,Node**);
Node*reverseList(Node*,Node**);
void insertAfter(Node*,Node**,int,int);
Node* insertBefore(Node*,int,int);
void printList(Node*);
Node*insertLast(Node*,Node**,Node*);
Node*createNode(int);
int search(Node*,int);
Node*Delete(Node*,Node**,int);
Node*deleteLast(Node*,Node**);

int main()
{
    int temp,ch,num;
    Node *newNode,*start,*last;
    start=last=NULL;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n_________________menu__________________\n");
        printf("1. insert at the end of list...\n");
        printf("2. print the list...\n");
        printf("3. search a speific item...\n");
        printf("4. insert after a specific node...\n");
        printf("5. insert a node before a specific node...\n");
        printf("6. delete a specific node...\n");
        printf("7. delete a last node...\n");
        printf("8. reverse the link list...\n");
        printf("9. sort the link list...\n");
        printf("10. sort the link list(another method)...\n");
        printf("11. exit...\n");

        printf("\nenter your choice : ");
        scanf("%d",&ch);

        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("enter the data part of the node that you want to insert :\n");
                scanf("%d",&temp);
                newNode=createNode(temp);
                start=insertLast(start,&last,newNode);
                break;
            case 2:
                printList(start);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("enter the data that you want to search : ");
                scanf("%d",&temp);
                if(search(start,temp))
                    printf("the number you entered was in the list");
                else
                    printf("the number you entered was not in the list");
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("enter the data of the node after which you want to insert new node : ");
                scanf("%d",&temp);
                printf("enter the data part of the node that you want to insert : ");
                scanf("%d",&num);
                insertAfter(start,&last,temp,num);
                break;
            case 5:
                printf("enter the data of the node before which you want to insert new node : ");
                scanf("%d",&temp);
                printf("enter the data part of the node that you want to insert : ");
                scanf("%d",&num);
                start=insertBefore(start,temp,num);
                break;
            case 6:
                printf("enter the data part of the node that you want to delete : ");
                scanf("%d",&temp);
                start=Delete(start,&last,temp);
                break;
            case 7:
                if(last==NULL)
                {
                    printf("the list is empty...you can't delete any node...");
                    break;
                }
                start=deleteLast(start,&last);
                break;
            case 8:
                start=reverseList(start,&last);
                break;
            case 9:
                start=sort(start,&last);
                break;
            case 10:
                start=sort2(start,&last);
                break;
            case 11:
                exit(1);
            default:
                printf("you have entered a wrong choice...enter a valid choice");
        }
    }
}

Node* createNode(int data)
{
    Node*newNode;
    newNode=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data=data;
    newNode->next=NULL;
    return newNode;
}

Node*insertLast(Node*start,Node**p2last,Node*newNode)
{
    if(*p2last==NULL)
    {
        *p2last=newNode;
        return newNode;
    }
    (*p2last)->next=newNode;
    *p2last=newNode;
    return start;
}

void printList(Node*start)
{
    printf("your list is as follows : \n");
    while(start)
    {
        printf("%d\t",start->data);
        start=start->next;
    }
}

int search(Node*start,int data)
{
    while(start)
    {
        if(start->data==data)
            return 1;
        start=start->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

void insertAfter(Node*start,Node**p2last,int data,int num)
{
    Node*newNode,*tmp;
    newNode=createNode(num);
    if(*p2last==NULL)
        printf("the list is empty...");
    tmp=start;
    while(tmp)
    {
        if(tmp->data==data)
            break;
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
    if(!tmp)
        printf("the number you enter was not in the list\n");
    else
    {
        newNode->next=tmp->next;
        tmp->next=newNode;
        if(tmp==*p2last)
            *p2last=newNode;
    }
}

Node*insertBefore(Node*start,int data,int num)
{
    Node *newNode,*prev,*tmp;
    prev=NULL;
    newNode=createNode(num);
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        printf("the list is empty...");
        return start;
    }
    tmp=start;
    while(tmp)
    {
        if(tmp->data==data)
            break;
        prev=tmp;
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
    if(!tmp)
        printf("the number you enter was not in the list\n");
    else if(prev==NULL)
    {
        newNode->next=start;
        start=newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        newNode->next=prev->next;
        prev->next=newNode;
    }
    return start;
}

Node*Delete(Node*start,Node**p2last,int data)
{
    Node*prev,*tmp;
    tmp=start;
    prev=NULL;
    while(tmp)
    {
        if(tmp->data==data)
            break;
        prev=tmp;
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }

    if(!tmp)
    {
        printf("the item you entered was not in the list...\n");
        return start;
    }
    if(tmp==start)
    {
        if((*p2last)==start)
            *p2last=NULL;
        return NULL;
    }
    prev->next=tmp->next;
    if(tmp==(*p2last))
        *p2last=prev;
    free(tmp);

    return start;
}

Node*deleteLast(Node*start,Node**p2last)
{
    return Delete(start,p2last,(*p2last)->data);
}

Node*reverseList(Node*start,Node**p2last)
{
    Node*ptr,*tmp,*prev;
    (*p2last)=start;
    prev=NULL;
    for(ptr=start;ptr;)
    {
        tmp=ptr->next;
        ptr->next=prev;
        prev=ptr;
        ptr=tmp;
    }
    return prev;
}

Node*sort(Node*start,Node**p2last)
{
    Node*ptr,*newNode,*tmp,*start1,*last1;
    start1=last1=NULL;
    while(start!=NULL)
    {
        tmp=ptr=start;
        while(ptr)
        {
            if(tmp->data > ptr->data)
                tmp=ptr;
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        newNode=createNode(tmp->data);
        start1=insertLast(start1,&last1,newNode);
        start=Delete(start,p2last,tmp->data);
    }
    *p2last=last1;
    return start1;
}

Node*sort2(Node*start,Node**p2last)
{
    int *arr,count=0,i,tmp,j;
    Node*ptr,*start1,*last1,*newNode;
    ptr=start;
    start1=last1=NULL;
    while(ptr)
    {
        count++;
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }

    arr=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*count);

    ptr=start;
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=ptr->data;    
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }

    /* sorting the array bubble */
    for(i=1;i<count;i++)
        for(j=0;j<count-i;j++)
            if(arr[j]>arr[j+1])
            {
                tmp=arr[j];
                arr[j]=arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1]=tmp;
            }

    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
        start1=insertLast(start1,&last1,createNode(arr[i]));
    *p2last=last1;
    return start1;
}
```